# Problema operadores rxjs, interceptor Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

tengo un spinner que quiero poner con un interceptor, tengo el siguiente codigo, pero el spinner **se queda pegado y no para.**

Estaba viendo con console.log, y **nunca entra** en el if del HttpResponse

```js
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private contador: number = 0;
  constructor(private service: SpinnerService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.contador++;
    if (this.contador === 1) {
        this.service.show();
    }
    let handleObs: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = next.handle(request);
    handleObs
    .pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        // realizar manejo del error
        this.contador--;
        return throwError(e)
       }),
      tap(e => {
       if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
          // si es respuesta exitosa
          this.contador--;
          if (this.contador<=0)
             this.service.hide();
        }
      })
    )
    return handleObs;

  }
}
```

El problema que tenia tambien, es que al ser solo cuando hay peticiones http, se terminaba cuando me daba un response y en ese transcurso de que yo manejo la data por ejemplo de un login y hago el navigate, en ese tiempo que manejo la data el spinner ya paro y se muestra de nuevo la pantalla anterior hasta que cambia a otra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí. Hay cambios. Ahora debe usarse el operador `pipe()` y dentro agregar los operadores que se desean aplicar al observable. Y `catch` sería `catchError` y `do` sería `tap`

```
observable$
    .pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        // realizar manejo del error
        return throwError(e)
       }),
      tap(e => {
       if(e instanceof HttpResponse){
          // si es respuesta exitosa
        }
      })
    )
```

Te comparto la documentación de Angular para manejo de errores como referencia [Manejo de errroes](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors)

Comment: Gracias ,lo actualize, pero tengo un problema. Ahora el spinner no para, se queda pegado. te comparto como quedo el codigo, actualizando en la pregunta

Comment: Cierto. Actualicé la respuesta. En el tap la variable se llama `e` no `event`.

Comment: Lobo, me ayudarias con esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457008/cancelar-peticiones-angular-interceptor